# Delete individual entries of input field suggestions

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to delete individual input field suggestions in Firefox, rather than deleting all of them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>?

For example, in an input field like the following, I'd like to remove the suggestion for the yahoo address, without removing the suggestion for the gmail address:
[image]

Alternatively, I would also be okay with deleting suggstions specific to a webseite or input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out this is possible by selecting the corresponding suggestion (via arrow keys or mouse hover) and simply pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: For MacOS, it is Shift + Del.